# How to link existing tables in database to Django Models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-database, django-database-functions

I am learning Django and i need to know whether i can link a table already present in the database to a model (since, i heard that tables are created by Django for whatever models we are creating inside django app ).

If so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`inspectdb` works fine now. (Django 1.7+) Simply running manage.py inspectdb will create classes for all tables in database and display on console.

```
 $ python manage.py inspectdb
```

Save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection:

```
 $ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

[Read further from here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/legacy-databases/)